# Concurrent Multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to understand how multithreading works. I've written the following code
`

```
void handler(void *arg)
{
    printf("Printf from cleanup handler: %s\n", (char*)arg);
}

void print(const char *msg)
{
    printf("%7s: Pid=%d Tid:%lu\n", msg, getpid(), pthread_self());
}

void* thread_function1(void *args)
{
    printf("Received: %d\n", (int)args);
    print("Thread");
    pthread_cleanup_push(handler, "hello");
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
    printf("Thread Done\n");    
    return (void *) 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;
    void *tret;
    if(pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, thread_function1, (void *)1))
        exit(1);
    if(pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, thread_function1, (void *)2))
        exit(1);
//  pthread_join(tid2, &tret);
//  pthread_join(tid1, &tret);
}
```

The problem with this code is that the main completes its execution before `thread_function1` could complete its execution. If both the comments are removed then `thread 2` is executed only after `thread 1` has completeted  its execution.

What I want to do is have `thread 1` and `thread 2` execute simultaneously and `main` should wait for completion of both the threads.

Comment: Do the threads do a (non-trivial) amount of work? Could it be that `thread_function1` finishes before the second thread is even created?

Comment: @WanderNauta I've updated the question. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem with this code is that the main completes its execution before thread_function1 could complete its execution.

That's because when the main thread exits, the process dies including all threads. You can instead call `pthread_exit(0)` from the main thread so that the rest of the threads continue execution and the main thread exits.

> If both the comments are removed then thread 2 is executed only after thread 1 has completeted its execution.

That's not true. i.e. `tid1` and `tid2` are executed simultaneously after they are created ("simultaneous execution" depends on your hardware, scheduling policy etc -- but as far as you program is concerned, they can be considered as being executed simultaneously). `pthread_join()` doesn't control the order of threads' execution. It only affects the order in which the main thread *waits* for the completion of the threads i.e. main thread waits for `tid2` to complete first and then waits for `tid1` (if you ncomment those two lines).

Comment: I get the output as "Received: 1 \n Printf from cleanup handler: hello \n Received: 2 \n Printf from cleanup handler: hello"
This means thread 2 was executed only after thread 1 was completed. Am I missing something?

Comment: The order is not fixed. Try executing it repeatedly a few times and you'll probably see "Received 2" first and then "Received 1".

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried running it multiple times and it works exactly as you mentioned. Thank you ! :)

Comment: I also another problem in your updated code: `thread_function1` doesn't have a declaration when you first use it. Either move it *above* the main function. Or, declare a prototype for it before main(): `void *thread_function1(void*);`. Good luck!

Comment: This is not the real code. I've added the code just to show what I'm doing. I'll edit the question. Thanks though :)